# how to make sense of the App downloads in iTunes Connect?

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store-connect

My first App is released. Am quite confused with what iTunes Connect is displaying. Can someone please help me interpret the data?

When we open 'manage your apps', there is a graph like this

[image]

It says 5 for Oct 4th and 31 for Oct 5th. What does this mean? Does the 31 on Oct 5th include the 5 on Oct 4th (is it cumulative)? Or should I calculate the 'total app downloads' as 5+31 = 36 so far?

ALso, in the 'top markets' table below, it shows some countries and then shows +1,+4,+8 etc. What are these? For example '+1 in Venezuela' -> does this mean 1 'new' download (not accounting for how many have already been already downloaded the previous days from this country) in Venezuela on the particular day of Oct 5th, or is it cumulative (i.e. sum total of all downloads since the beginning in the country Venezuela for the App)?

Comment: Fwiw you might get a better answer on the Apple developer forums..

Comment: User guide for [iTunes Connect
Sales and Trends](http://www.apple.com/itunesnews/docs/AppStoreReportingInstructions.pdf). hope it helps.

Comment: This question is not about programming. May be suitable for http://apple.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the count is not cumulative, it showing the downloads of each day. That means you have 5 downloads on 4th Oct and 31 downloads on 5th Oct that makes total of 36 downloads.
Also +1, +4, +8 etc its showing the change in the number from last week, so currently this number will be same as number written to left because you have zero downloads for last week.
As time pass your these number will you understand more about that.

Comment: Thank you @parser! simple, clean answer! couldn't believe that Apple could make something so simple to be complex that it calls for a stackoverflow question posting! ;)